# How to resize image after upload

Tags: php, image, upload, resize

I have an image upload form that works well. It uploads to a folder, but i want it to give the uploaded file a specific height and width so it fits on the page. Can someone help me with it?

Thanks!

```
    <?php


$uploadpath = 'upload/';     
$max_size = 2000;          
$alwidth = 250;            
$alheight = 400;           
$allowtype = array('bmp', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpe', 'png');        

if(isset($_FILES['fileup']) && strlen($_FILES['fileup']['name']) > 1) {
  $uploadpath = $uploadpath . basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']);       
  $sepext = explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['fileup']['name']));
  $type = end($sepext);       // gets extension
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name']);     
  $err = '';         


  if(!in_array($type, $allowtype)) $err .= 'The file: <b>'. $_FILES['fileup']['name']. '</b> not has the allowed extension type.';
  if($_FILES['fileup']['size'] > $max_size*1000) $err .= '<br/>Maximum file size must be: '. $max_size. ' KB.';
  if(isset($width) && isset($height) && ($width >= $alwidth || $height >= $alheight)) $err .= '<br/> Maximale waarden: '. $alwidth. ' x '. $alheight . '&nbsp probeer opnieuw';


  if($err == '') {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name'], $uploadpath)) { 
      echo "Uw afbeelding is succesvol opgeslagen";
    }
    else echo '<b>Unable to upload the file.</b>';
  }
  else echo $err;
}
?> 
<div style="width:500px;;margin:1em auto; width:333px; text-align:center;">
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
   <input type="file" name="fileup" /><br/>
  <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Upload" /> 
 </form>
</div>

</div>
</div></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this will work for you, atleast in beggining.

```
    if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" ){

        $uploadedfile = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);

    }else if($extension=="png"){

        $uploadedfile = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
        $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);

    }else{

        $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);

    }       

    $width = imagesx($src);
    $height = imagesy($src);


    $tmp_filename = _file_name_here_;


    // LARGE

    $new_width = YOUR_WIDTH ;
    $new_height = YOUR_HEIGHT ;
    $k_w = 1;
    $k_h = 1;
    $dst_x =0;
    $dst_y =0;
    $src_x =0;
    $src_y =0;

    //seclecting_offsets
    if($new_width>$width ){//by width
        $dst_x = ($new_width-$width)/2;
    }

    if($new_height>$height){//by height
        $dst_y = ($new_height-$height)/2;
    }

    if( $new_width$height){
            $src_x  = ($width-$new_width)/2;
        }else if ($new_width>$width){
                $src_y  = ($height-$new_height)/2;
        }else{
            if($k_h>$k_w){
                $src_x = round(($width-($new_width/$k_h))/2);
            }else{
                $src_y = round(($height-($new_height/$k_w))/2);
            }
        }
    }   

    //create new empty image with new size
    $tmp_large=imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

    // this function copies old image on to new, resizes and crops according to offsets we set before
    imagecopyresampled($tmp_large,$src,$dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y,$new_width-2*$dst_x, $new_height-2*$dst_y, $width-2*$src_x, $height-2*$src_y);

    // here we set where we want to save new image
    $filename = $sys_root.$tmp_filename .".png";

    // SAVE IMAGE
    imagepng($tmp_large,$filename);
```

Go thrue code, i tried to comment out actions, so you understand whats happening.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: you need to modify this code for your needs, not just paste it, please read it, and try to find connection with your code. Thats the only way how you can learn.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( $new_width$height){
}
```

// concatenate operator is missing here
// Modify this to

```
if( $new_width.height){}
```